# C# Webservice to copy datas from one DB to Another

Tags: c#, sql-server, modeling, system-information, system-integration

I need to make a webservice that take three arguments(**DataTable** dt, **string** connectionString, **string** table) to integrate the datas in **dt** to the given *database.[table]*, but not the same schema.

How can I sort this out please?

Comment: Instead of copying data all over the place why not have the other system pull data directly from the HR system via a view? Then there is no need to update remote data or anything like that which is likely to break. Use one source of data.

Comment: This is not a specific programming question, but rather an extremely broad software engineering problem. This is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please specify a specific problem, and remove all the unnecessary backstory.

Comment: @4castle, ok sir thank you, I just have a misunderstanding about the aim :/ after some help I'll remove It. I posted it yesterday in Quora but no one react !

Comment: @SeanLange, oh it's a good idea ! I'll discuss it with my framing internship when available.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> if an employee's datas changed in HR database automatically FD system
>   must notified to refresh his database

Consider looking at [SQL Server Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication) (or) [AlwaysOn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/always-on-availability-groups-sql-server) feature for this same purpose. Specifically you should look at `Transactional Replication`

Comment: Rahul thank you so much, I'll look at it

Comment: done, thank you for your help